# Can we get certain record as a top most record in elastic search paginated response java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a requirement where i need to to fetch all the users using elastic search for the landing page using pagination where in topmost/first record should be from current logged in user.

I am able to get the paginated response for all the users using match all query but i am not able to get the current user record as top most record in paginated response.

is it possible to achieve this using elastic search query, my elastic search version is 7.6.0

here is my code

```
    SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    BoolQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    long totalHits;
    builder.must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
    builder.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(book.squadMemberMongoId.keyword)); // squad member must be present

    sourceBuilder.from(from);
    sourceBuilder.size(size);
    sourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
    sourceBuilder.trackTotalHitsUpTo();
    sourceBuilder.sort((SortBuilders.fieldSort("book.eaLastName.keyword").order(SortOrder.ASC)));
    sourceBuilder.query(builder);
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
// client is instance of RestHighLevelClient        
   response=client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

   SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
```

is there any way where i can make above query to return current logged in user / specific record in top of the response list (current logged user can be identified by squadMemberMongoId field in data)

Sample Data:

```
{
  "submissionId": "232323237",
  "revision": 2,
  "author": {
  "country": "xyz",
  "email": "john.doe@informa.com",
  "name": "john doe"
},
"book": {
 "eaLastName" : "xyzea"
 "squad": "John",
 "squadMemberMongoId": 12345678
}
....
```

}

submissionId is the index key here

expected response:

If i have multiple different submissions with different submission ids and different squadMemberMongoId under book , when i make a query i want record with specific squadMemberMongoId to be on top of the response  then followed by other records with different id's, entire response set has to be paginated

Comment: Can you please povide index mapping, sample data and expected result from it.

Comment: I am able to achieve my case by grouping my queries in FunctionScoreQueryBuilder and providing each set with weight factor, group with highest factor is returned on top in complete result set
currently i am testing if it works allways

Comment: Have you considered something like the "should" query here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18486519/2691904
If you set minimum_number_should_match to 0 it should still return all records, but will let you give a boost to the on with the matching squadMemberMongoId?